# Parse XML in iOS tableview

Tags: swift, xml

I am trying to parse XML into my table view. I wanted to fetch data and display it in my swift application.I am trying to use zillow api to fetch the data.

I want to be able to replace the address with whatever the user selects in the first tableview. Then I want to use the zillow api to display some results about the house.

I want to be able to fetch the property information like year built, lot size and so forth. I also really want to display house images as well.  I use Alamofire normally for my other requests. But I do not see much information out there for fetching this data. I looked into another post but did not get much luck.

I have the same url here

```
url = http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm?zws-id=<ZillowIDKey>&address=2114+Bigelow+Ave&citystatezip=Seattle%2C+WA

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SearchResults:searchresults xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd http://www.zillowstatic.com/vstatic/80d5e73/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SearchResults="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd">
    <request>
        <address>2114 Bigelow Ave</address>
        <citystatezip>Seattle, WA</citystatezip>
    </request>
    <message>
        <text>Request successfully processed</text>
        <code>0</code>
    </message>
    <response>
        <results>
            <result>
                <zpid>48749425</zpid>
                <links>
                    <homedetails>http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2114-Bigelow-Ave-N-Seattle-WA-98109/48749425_zpid/</homedetails>
                    <graphsanddata>http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2114-Bigelow-Ave-N-Seattle-WA-98109/48749425_zpid/#charts-and-data</graphsanddata>
                    <mapthishome>http://www.zillow.com/homes/48749425_zpid/</mapthishome>
                    <comparables>http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/48749425_zpid/</comparables>
                </links>
                <address>
                    <street>2114 Bigelow Ave N</street>
                    <zipcode>98109</zipcode>
                    <city>Seattle</city>
                    <state>WA</state>
                    <latitude>47.637934</latitude>
                    <longitude>-122.347936</longitude>
                </address>
                <FIPScounty>53033</FIPScounty>
                <useCode>SingleFamily</useCode>
                <taxAssessmentYear>2017</taxAssessmentYear>
                <taxAssessment>1326000.0</taxAssessment>
                <yearBuilt>1924</yearBuilt>
                <lotSizeSqFt>4680</lotSizeSqFt>
                <finishedSqFt>3470</finishedSqFt>
                <bathrooms>3.0</bathrooms>
                <bedrooms>4</bedrooms>
                <lastSoldDate>11/26/2008</lastSoldDate>
                <lastSoldPrice currency="USD">995000</lastSoldPrice>
                <zestimate>
                    <amount currency="USD">1894713</amount>
                    <last-updated>10/23/2019</last-updated>
                    <oneWeekChange deprecated="true"></oneWeekChange>
                    <valueChange duration="30" currency="USD">-15690</valueChange>
                    <valuationRange>
                        <low currency="USD">1743136</low>
                        <high currency="USD">2065237</high>
                    </valuationRange>
                    <percentile>0</percentile>
                </zestimate>
                <localRealEstate>
                    <region name="East Queen Anne" id="271856" type="neighborhood">
                        <zindexValue>870,700</zindexValue>
                        <links>
                            <overview>http://www.zillow.com/local-info/WA-Seattle/East-Queen-Anne/r_271856/</overview>
                            <forSaleByOwner>http://www.zillow.com/east-queen-anne-seattle-wa/fsbo/</forSaleByOwner>
                            <forSale>http://www.zillow.com/east-queen-anne-seattle-wa/</forSale>
                        </links>
                    </region>
                </localRealEstate>
            </result>
        </results>
    </response>
```

I tried to parse the url and have alamofire read it using the response function. But it did not work for me. Anyone have a suggestion on how to display this correctly? Thanks

Comment: Never include your API key in a question. Luckily this API key is free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in `XMLparser`

```
let urlString = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm?zws-id=X1-ZWz17klcv16d57_9hc6e&address=2114+Bigelow+Ave&citystatezip=Seattle%2C+WA"

AF.request(urlString).response { response in

  let parser = XMLParser(data: response)
    parser?.delegate = self

    if (parser?.parse())! {
        print(self.results)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I just have to update the Alamofire code. Cannot convert value of type 'DefaultDataResponse' to expected argument type 'Data'. I will have to take a look.